# Replace decimal value with a different value according to its current value in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I've got a table with items and their prices.  What I want to do is change the decimal places of the prices based on a rounding table.  If the price ends in .01-.09, the decimal place should end in .94.  If it ends in .10-.21, it should end in .95.  If it ends in .22-.38, it should end in .96 and so on.

So a price of $5.35 would become $5.96, and $7.12 would become $7.95.

Is there a way of doing this?  I'm using Sql Server 2014.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `%` and `CASE`:

```
WITH prices AS (
   SELECT CAST(5.35 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS p
)
SELECT p,
       CAST(CAST(p AS INT) + 
         CASE WHEN p%1.0 BETWEEN .01 AND .09 THEN .94
              WHEN p%1.0 BETWEEN .10 AND .21 THEN .95
              WHEN p%1.0 BETWEEN .22 AND .38 THEN .96
              ELSE 0  -- default
         END AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS new_price
FROM prices;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/HMHLDR32047)**

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly.  I learned something new today!  You can convert a decimal data type to int to drop numbers after the decimal.  And also it looks like p%1.0 shows only the decimal value.  I thought % was just for wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [PARSENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql) function to get the decimal part and compare it with your desired ranges.

```
DECLARE @number decimal(18,2) = 12.11

SELECT CAST(PARSENAME(@number,2) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) +
(CASE WHEN PARSENAME(@number,1) BETWEEN 1 AND 9 THEN 0.94
      WHEN PARSENAME(@number,1) BETWEEN 10 AND 21 THEN 0.95
      WHEN PARSENAME(@number,1) BETWEEN 22 AND 38 THEN 0.96
      ELSE @number END
 )
```

*Result*

**12.95**